# Google Play Developer Console - watch all reviews

Tags: android, google-play

I just want the simple and obvious ability to watch all reviews and ratings of my published app, and the users who gave them. No matter what language, locale or country they were written from. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To see your app's ratings & reviews:

1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, click Ratings & Reviews.

Near the top of the page under "Ratings & Reviews", you can see the total number of ratings, a summary of star ratings, and the average rating for your app.

You can also download monthly reports about your apps. There are 2 types of reports available: 1) detailed reports (for reviews) and aggregated reports (for ratings). To download reports:

1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Click Reports Reports.
3. On the left menu, select a report.
4. Under “Application”, type and select your app’s name.
5. Select a year and month to download your report.

References: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138230
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not answer my question. I want the ability to see ALL reviews & ratings AND the users who gave them in a simple one report. Taking your first suggestion will not show me the users and taking your 2nd suggestion will force me to download a report for each specific month. Kindda strange this is such a special requirement to ask for...